# What are convenient uml tools to create geodatabase models?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, esri-geodatabase, uml, enterprise-architect

I used to model databases with Microsoft Office Visio, then export the model to xml and import geodatabase schema to GDB with ArcGIS tools.
Since Microsoft no longer support Visio export to xml, what are the alternatives?

---

Has anyone used Enterprise Architect? Is it convenient for designing Geodatabases for ArcGIS?

---

I have tried ArcGIS Diagrammer (for [ArcGIS 9.2/9.3](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15166) or for [ArcGIS 10](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=F12ADF8F-1422-2418-34B2-C276C6BCCF98)) but it is not so convenient..

Answer (score 4):

The Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect website has a posting on UML support for [ArcGIS Geodatabase Design](http://www.sparxsystems.com/arcgis).

There is a tutorial and a video demonstration explaining how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been told that using ArcGIS Diagrammer and [GDB X-Ray](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15119) in conjunction with Visio can do most of what would be needed.

Comment: Link now only goes to a generic Code Sharing page.